# rubys> cd command not working in command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just getting into ruby and am trying to execute a walkthrough from Sam Ruby's Agile web development.

I've created a directory using mkdir work

Next i'm instructed to open a terminal and type rubys> cd work

The error I'm getting reads:
No command 'rubys' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ruby' from package 'ruby' (main)
rubys: command not found

Can anyone inform me of what I'm doing wrong?
I've also tried changing from ~ to the work directory before entering my command.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to [SuperUser](http://SuperUser.Com/). I don't think "how do I type commands into the command line" is really a question for "professional and enthusiast programmers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this book, `rubys>` is a command prompt, much like you have `C:\>` in the Windows terminal.

Ignore that first bit and everything should start working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're doing it wrong.

```
mkdir work
```

creates a directory called "work". It has nothing to do with Ruby.

```
cd work
```

will then change into that directory. Forget about the `rubys>`.